# String compare function in C

Tags: c, string

```
map[0][4]='\0';
city1[0][4]='\0';
strcpy(map[0],city1[0]);
map[0][0]='z';
printf("%s",map[0]);
printf("%s",city1[0]);
printf("%d \n",strcmp(map[0],city1[0]));
```

The output of this function is `zail
nail
12`

Why it is so? What I did not understand about `strcmp`? Why 12 and not any other number?

Comment: I'm amazed you are getting anything readable at all.  How are your arrays initialized and declared?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question,

```
strcmp("zail", "nail")
```

is evaluating to 12 because it's subtracting the 'n' in "nail" from the 'z' in "zail", and 'z' - 'n' = 12.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting random junk because you're not initializing your arrays properly.

Instead of

```
map[0][4]='\0';
city1[0][4]='\0';
```

Try

```
memset(map[0], '\0', sizeof(map[0]));
memset(city1[0], '\0', sizeof(city1[0]));
```

Comment: No - at least use sizeof() so that it works for any size "char",

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - fair enough.